# Getting a specific string pattern

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a database with a string column, this database looks like this:

```
structure(list(variables = c("data$Ageee[data$Beneficiary == 1] and data$Age[data$Beneficiary == 0]",
"data$var[data$Beneficiary == 1] and data$Age[data$Beneficiary == 0]",
"data$variable_test[data$Beneficiary == 1] and data$Age[data$Beneficiary == 0]"
), values = c(0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

However, I would like to get a new column considering the text after the first `$` and before the first `[`, so I get:

```
structure(list(variables = c("Ageee", "var", "variable_test"
), values = c(0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `sub` to capture the word (`(\\w+`) after the `$` - `$` is a metacharacter in regex that denotes the end of the string, so it is escaped (`\\`)

```
df1$variables <- sub("\\w+\\$(\\w+).*", "\\1", df1$variables)
```

-output

```
> df1
      variables values
1         Ageee      0
2           var      0
3 variable_test      0
```

Comment: What would happen if we had the strings in single quotes, like: ``structure(list(variables = c("data$`Ageee in Years`[data$Beneficiary == 1] and data$`Age in Years`[data$ Beneficiary == 0]",
"data$var[data$Beneficiary == 1] and data$Age[data$Beneficiary == 0]",
"data$variable_test[data$Beneficiary == 1] and data$Age[data$Beneficiary == 0]"
), values = c(0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))`` @Akrun

Comment: @Erivelton you may change the code `(\\w+)` to `sub("\\w+\\$([^[]+)\\[.*", "\\1", df1$variables)` i..e characters that are not a `[` is captured with (`([^[]+)`)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stringr` with `str_extract` and `str_remove`, with a positive lookbehind to ascertain the desired pattern comes right after the first `$`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(variables = str_extract(variables, "(<?\\$)\\w+")%>%
                  str_remove('\\$'))

      variables values
1         Ageee      0
2           var      0
3 variable_test      0
```